# Vertical text in windows form using onPaint

Tags: vb.net, button

I found this [Vertical Text on Button Control](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/79e03a5d-624c-4c18-a350-b07ea7d4a8f1/vertical-text-on-button-control?forum=Vsexpressvb) I thought that looks easy but I can't get it to work.

```
Public Class VerticalButton3

    Inherits System.Windows.Forms.Button

    Private _VerticalText As String
    Public Property VerticalText() As String
        Get
            Return _VerticalText
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            _VerticalText = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Private Fmt As New StringFormat

    Public Sub New()
        Fmt.Alignment = StringAlignment.Center
        Fmt.LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Center
    End Sub

    Protected Overrides Sub OnPaint(ByVal PaintEvt As System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs)
        MyBase.OnPaint (PaintEvt)
        PaintEvt.Graphics.TranslateTransform(Width, 0)
        PaintEvt.Graphics.RotateTransform (90)
        PaintEvt.Graphics.DrawString(_VerticalText, Font, Brushes.Black, New Rectangle(0, 0, Height, Width), Fmt)
    End Sub

End Class
```

[image: Button] 
But I get both vertical and horizontal text.

I tried to use `Public Overrides Property Text()` similar to [Vertical Label Control in VB.NET](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/11523/Vertical-Label-Control-in-VB-NET) but that didn't work either

How do I get the vertical text only?

Comment: And the `Text` property is empty?

Comment: It works fine for me. Make sure the `Text` property is not set.

Comment: When I set Text to "" then it worked, but I wasn't sure how to set the text after that. I guess too many changes obscured what was happening. But Bansi has answered that question.

Comment: When you call `MyBase.OnPaint (PaintEvt)` the normal horizontal text and all of the button gets painted. On the next 3 lines you paint your vertical text. so both show up

Comment: Oh that's very interesting.

Comment: The problem with your code is that WM_GETTEXT message is sent every time the button is to be drawn. So if you get this message and return 0 then your original text will not be drawn.

Comment: @valter Interesting, but I wouldn't know how to do that.

Comment: I have been programming with c and c++ for many years and to do this i am subclassing the button and intercept the WM_GETTEXT message returning zero. I havent tried that in vb though, thats why i didn't post an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested your code. It works as you require if you set the `Text` Property to ""

Here is the code I tried

```
Private WithEvents vbtn As New VerticalButton3
Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    vbtn.Top = 0
    vbtn.Left = 0
    vbtn.Text = "" ' Note Text property is set to ""
    vbtn.VerticalText = "Vertical"
    vbtn.Height = 100
    Controls.Add(vbtn)

End Sub
```

Alternatively you can use `Text=""` in the Constructor of your class

```
Public Sub New()
    Fmt.Alignment = StringAlignment.Center
    Fmt.LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Center
    Text = ""
End Sub
```

Edit: I think it is a better to override the `Text` Property itself, because if by mistake the `Text` property is set the both may show up. Here is how you  can override the `Text` Property (you may no longer need the `VerticalText` property).

```
Public Shadows Property Text
    Get
        Return _VerticalText
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value)
        _VerticalText = value
    End Set
End Property
```

Comment: What about using Public Overrides instead of Public Shadows?

Comment: Well I tried to use `Public Overrides` but couldn't get it to work

Comment: Shadows Hides the property from the class `System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase` I don't exactly know why technically Override don't work here. but practically it don't work